# Самый просто способ для перевода строки в число(и наоборот) в C++

Tags: c++

Какой самый простой способ перевести int в string и из string в int?

Comment: std::stoi std::to_string

Comment: `atoi` и `itoa`

Comment: @ПавелЕриков вообщето просили string, а не сишные char* буфера.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков хах сидел и ждал пока вы это напишите. Как же не хочется с вами вообще общаться :) А так я хотел изначально написать про те функции, которые указали вы, но как вариант решил и про `atoi` и `itoa` написать. Почему нет?